# Typescript definitions for google app scripts JSON

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script

Are there Typescript definitions for the raw JSON schema when building a Google App Script using a cloud function, as described here: https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/alternate-runtimes-quickstart

I see `@types/google-apps-script` but that doesn't seem to define the expected JSON schema (i assume when [`printJSON()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/authorization-exception#printJson()) is ultimately called)

Alternatively, is there a way to import the App Script library, so I can call `printJSON()` myself and use their framework?

```
{
    "action": {
      "navigations": [
        {
          "pushCard": {
            "header": {
              "title": "Cats!"
            },
            "sections": [
              {
                "widgets": [
                  {
                    "textParagraph": {
                      "text": "Your random cat:"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "image": {
                      "imageUrl": "https://cataas.com/cat"
                     }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

As you described in the question, there is a published interface for CardService in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/40fd84d8630e9fc39efb9b402f6c18b9d495af44/types/google-apps-script/google-apps-script.card-service.d.ts#L30-L69), which [according to this alternate runtimes blog post](https://developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/building-g-suite-add-ons-with-your-favorite-tech-stack.html) builds a protobuf that matches the JSON format expected. Though CardService and the JSON format are likely derived from the same protobuf, I could not find that source in a publicly-accessible place.

Though they're not in TypeScript format, there is a ["sample JSON schemas" section](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes#sample_json_schemas) in the full [non-quickstart Alternate Runtime docs](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/guides/alternate-runtimes), which you could then convert to TypeScript declarations using a library like [json-schema-to-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-typescript).

Comment: unfortunately those aren't really proper schemas, and are only examples, so can't be converted to Typescript (automatically, at least). :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typeof` to get type of an object.

```
const obj={
    "action": {
      "navigations": [
        {
          "pushCard": {
            "header": {
              "title": "Cats!"
            },
            "sections": [
              {
                "widgets": [
                  {
                    "textParagraph": {
                      "text": "Your random cat:"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "image": {
                      "imageUrl": "https://cataas.com/cat"
                     }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };
 
 type mytype = typeof obj
```